# HTML Table - Iterate over multiple Lists and Create a Table

Tags: python, html

I have 3 lists of data that i would like to print out as a Table in HTML.

Lists
ipaddress [10.1.1.0,10.1.1.1,10.1.1.2,10.1.1.3]

State [Full,Full,Full,Full]

Interface [ge0,ge1,ge2,ge3]

ID [ 0,1,2,3]

I would like to Print above rows as a table under Table Column as rows.

Table Header

Address Interface State ID

I cant seem to figure out the proper for loops logic to print this as a table, here is what i have currently.

```
{%extends "home/layout.html"%}
{% block body%}
<h1 style="text-align:center;">Here is the Inventory </h1>
<li> {{ospfneighboraddress}}</li>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Address</th>
        <th scope="col">Interface</th>
        <th scope="col">State</th>
        <th scope="col">ID</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for ospfaddress in ospfneighboraddress %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ ospfaddress }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
</table>

{%endblock%}
```

ospfneighboraddress is the first IP address list, rest are also lists

Here are other list names:

ospfneighborinterface

ospfneighborstate

ospfneighborID

How do print next three lists for each IP address ?

Comment: Use `zip()` to loop over all 3 tables in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html>
        <head>
            
        </head>
        <body>
            
    <table border="1"> 
    
    <tr>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Interface</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>ID</th>
        
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td>10.1.1.0</td>
        <td>ge0</td>
        <td>Full</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td>10.1.1.1</td>
        <td>ge1</td>
        <td>Full</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td>10.1.1.2</td>
        <td>ge2</td>
        <td>Full</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td>10.1.1.3</td>
        <td>ge3</td>
        <td>Full</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    
    </table>
    
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks but this is static data. I need a for loop that iterates over it as data will change

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).